# Rails: when users places order, how to send an order email to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce

I am building an rails based e-commerce application first time. I want to send an email to user when he submits the order, like the way we get receipt on email when we place order on e.g. mealnut.com or fab.com. I was searching for tutorials but not getting related to order submit emails. Every where user sign up or reset etc.

Has any one implemented it? or know any resource/tutorial in rails?

Your guidance/help will be appreciated!

Comment: Giving a detailed recommendation means requiring a lot more details, so some general advice: In the [Rails Guides on ActionMailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) you'll be walked through all steps that would be required in your case too, but you'll need to adapt them for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot/not suitable use Devise mailer (since devise mailer is for User authentication purposes). What you could do is, you could use a observer class to send e-mails

Ex:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   #your standard order code
end

class OrderObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_create(order)
    #Email sending code  
  end

end
```

This OrderObserver sends an email when a Order#create is finished. [Read more about observer class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html)

Regarding sending email with rails3 [check this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3), and its same as sending emails for forgotpassword / signup etc, it's just that content is different.

Comment: Observers are being deprecated in rails 4 I believe.  I would keep the after_create in your order model.  BUT.  you might not be triggering off create.  you might want to trigger when the state of the order goes from in-progress to PAID.

Answer (score 3):

First generate the mailer for writing required actions.

```
rails g mailer UserMailer
```

then in **app/mailers/user_mailer.rb** file

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def order_confirmation(user, order)
    @user = user
    @order = order
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Order has been received')
  end
end
```

and the view content for the email would be like this `app/views/user_mailer/order_confirmation.html.erb`

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>

You have successfully placed an order with us.
Please find the details of order....
#.............
```

then in the controller action, where you will create a order, place the below line after creating the order to send an email

```
UserMailer.order_confirmation(user, order).deliver
```

Go through the [action mailer tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid sending an email is a fairly standard procedure.. and the tutorials you've found are probably applicable. You need to understand that triggering a message to be sent can be done from any controller action.. in your case you'll want the order create action.

After reading the following:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised?view=asciicast

You can make the necessary changes and call the mailer from your order create action:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    if @order.save
      UserMailer.order_confirmation(@order, @user).deliver
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Order Completed Successfully."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The reason I am using UserMailer in the above is because you will likely want to set up a mailer that sends messages to Users, but you could call it OrderMailer if you wanted.

Comment: i have a devise mailer. So confused. Should i use UserMailer? or devise mailer can be used?

Comment: No prob, glad it helped you :)